# CPLEX summation constraint

Tags: cplex, opl

Could you help me to identify the error regarding summation constraint in CPLEX?

```
ctbackorderBalanceThrowPeriodsa:
    forall (i in part, h in period) {
        if (h == 1) {
            demand[i, h] == production[i, h] + iniinventory[i] - inibackorder[i] - inventory[i, h] + backorder[i, h];   
        } else {
            demand[i, h] == production[i, h] + inventory[i, h - 1]  - backorder[i, h - 1] - inventory[i, h] + backorder[i, h];
        }   
    }

ctDailyWorkHr:
    forall (h in period) {
        sum(i in part) (production[i, h] * prodStd[i]) <= sum(w in worker) workHr[w, h];
    }

ctworkHrperPeriod:
    forall (w in worker,i in part, h in period) {
        workHr[w, h] >= 10.50 + 100000000 * (1 - x[w, i, h]);
        workHr[w, h] <= 10.50 - 100000000 * (1 - x[w, i, h]);
    }

ctWorkOneShiftPerDay:
    forall(w in worker, i in part, h in period) {
        sum (i in part) x[w, i, h] <= 1;
    }
```

I have problem in the `x` (binary variable) `sum` in the last constraint.

Comment: Why are you creating a sum over i in part inside a forall that also goes over all i in part?

Comment: Hi, can you post .mod and .dat ? regards

Comment: I cannot edit the question, but you can access all cplex model in [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uds59nrlmkjvj6bRh1N9tcK_8Sw6NH0p) @Alex Fleischer

Comment: Please give me an comment throw this project @TimChippingtonDerrick

Comment: Please check the Run Configuration 2

Comment: What is that last set of sum constraints supposed to mean in the real world? What is the constraint trying to do?

Comment: ctspindleArrangement: means for group of parts has the same characteristics (ltmovement and spindle), the total spindles need each group in specific period is x[w, i, h] * spindle (15 or 20) have to the common multiple of (60 or 40). (Set up of machine requirement)

Comment: ctworkerMustCompleteJobSize; means each worker, have to finish the lot size per part, it should be 400pcs or 500pcs in planning time.

Comment: I still have problem to build a constraint to minimize the changing part throw periods in worker, cause worker need setuptime when change part A to part B